# The instance of entity type 'AppUser' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Hopefully someone can help a fairly novice EF/ asp.net core dev...

One of my methods is failing on 'context.Add(item)'

The Model:

```cs
public class Component : Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ComponentName { get; set; }
    public string ComponentDescription { get; set; }
}
```

The method that fails ('_user' is AppUser which is set in the constructor):

```cs
public async Task<bool> UpdateComponentOwnerAsync(ComponentOwner componentOwner)
{
    var co = new ComponentOwner();
    bool success = false;
    try
    {
        if (componentOwner.Id == 0)
        {
            co.Component = componentOwner.Component;
            co.User = componentOwner.User;
            co.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
            co.UpdatedBy = "Someone";
        }
        else
        {
            co = componentOwner;
        }

        var coNew = (ComponentOwner)await SaveItem(co);
```

```cs
private async Task<Item> SaveItem(Item item)
{
    using var context = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
    try
    {
        context.Users.Attach(_user);

        if (item.Id == 0)
        {
            context.Add(item);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        }
```

The error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'AppUser' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

Removing 'context.Users.Attach(_user)' results in the following SQL Exception, SO this does need to stay in it seems:

> SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AspNetUsers'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetUsers'. The duplicate key value is (7344f007-4463-46ab-b435-651fb9e0e29a).
> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Components' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
> The statement has been terminated.

I've looked at similar posts and they all suggest that it's due to the scope being incorrect or 'AppUser being tracked. A scope isn't required as far as I can tell however (in my program.cs file, I have the following:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<DBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));`
```

and I can't see why AppUser would be being tracked elsewhere.

Hopefully someone can tell me where I'm going wrong!

Comment: You say `co = componentOwner;` and after that try to add it to the database once again?

Comment: co = componentOwner comes before it's added to the database.

Comment: At the moment `co = componentOwner` co "is" componentOwner, so you try to add componentOwner again.

Comment: I don't understand.. co is a new variable. componentOwner is an existing variable. I then say that co equals componentOwner. this is allowing me to either use the object sent across, or to create a new object from scratch. I'm not adding componentOwner twice...

Comment: Do you understand the difference between value and reference types?

Answer (score 1):

Your trying to add a record that already exists.  `Context.Add` and `Context.Update` do exactly what they say.

If you don't fully understand the differences between value and reference types I suggest you start reading.

In `UpdateComponentOwnerAsync` if `componentOwner` is an existing record then `componentOwner.Id` is not `0`.

Therefore

```cs
co = componentOwner;
```

assigns the `componentOwner` reference to `co`.

You then call `SaveItem(co)` which attempts to do a

```cs
context.Add(item [actually co])
```

And fails.  `co` points to the same reference as `componentOwner` passed in to `UpdateComponentOwnerAsync`.  As you obtained `componentOwner` from the database in the first place, then you have a duplicate id.

You don't show how you obtained `componentOwner` and what logic sets it's Id to `0`, so I'm not in a position to suggest a meaningful solution.

A couple of pointers:

1. You should differentiate in your code and data pipeline between Updates and Creates/Adds.  It makes the logic more straightforward and easier to understand.
2. Check the return value of `context.SaveChangesAsync`. You should get back `1` i.e. one record updated/created.